# Android Development - Using Inputstream/BufferStream, how do I throw all the lines of a text file into an array?

Tags: java, android

This is another question. So it seems that I have already set up the code with InputStream and Bufferstream to retrieve a String from a text file using this code:

```
// Read Text File entitled wordsEn.txt 
    public String readFromFile() {
        String words = "";

        try { 
            InputStream inputstream = openFileInput("wordsEn.txt");
            if (inputstream != null) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }
                inputstream.close();
                words = stringBuilder.toString();
            }




        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }



        return words;
    }
```

So what I want to do is store each string on each line of the text file into an array. I then want to be able to use this array to select a random string everytime I press a button.

Let me know.
Thanks
Colin

Comment: You're doing everything you need to do now... Just use a collection type of some kind which is resizeable, like an ArrayList, or LinkedList... add each line to it. When the file is done being parsed, create an array the same size as the collecion, and copy the values into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put below line into your class varialble

```
ArrayList<String> wordLineArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Than use add method array list to add each line of word into it.

```
wordLineArray.add(receiveString);
```

Use this line before appending it to previous buffer.

Now use this arraylist as per your requirment.

If it is helpful to you than don't forget to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BreakIterator.getLineInstance(). Set the text to your "words" string, then iterate through each line, adding each line to a String[] array.